# Fatal error: wp-settings.php on line 199

Tags: php, wp-admin, debug, fatal-error, file-manager

I'd love to know how to get back into wp-admin and get my site back online.

I contacted GoDaddy tech support again today and the PHP is supposedly updating.. Wordpress has been complaining about the older version of PHP it had a while back, as of 5 months ago, a GoDaddy rep told me I had to wait for the devs to switch me over at their convenience... Sadly, now I can't access wordress admin at all, I can only see this error message when I go to my URL:

> Warning:
> require(/home/content/60/11745860/html/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/content/60/11745860/html/wp-settings.php on line 199
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/home/content/60/11745860/html/wp-includes/class-wp-post.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_6/lib/php') in
> /home/content/60/11745860/html/wp-settings.php on line 199

Can I find this path / php file with the basic GoDaddy hosting File Manager? Should I wait for it to fix itself? Perhaps I should give up and build a new site? Any advise would be much appreciated. Thanks! - Teale Rose

Comment: You can access/find those files using the GoDaddy File Manager, but I suspect you'll find them and then still be left with nothing resolved.  Unless of course your site has somehow been compromised (plausible on GoDaddy Shared Hosting if that's what you're on) and the file has been removed.  I don't remember exactly how their structure works over there but that file should be in the main directory that WordPress is in.  So look for `home` or `public_html` or `www` and check in there.  if you see `wp-admin` or `wp-config.php` or `wp-content` you know you're in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what this is saying is that the file is not where the system is expecting it to be. If you have FTP access you could go in and replace the wp-includes folder with the one from a fresh download of WordPress.

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I appreciate the input. I was able to upload a fresh wp-includes folder. Alas, now it is giving me this: > Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_unregister_GLOBALS() in /home/content/60/11745860/html/wp-settings.php on line 80

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tony and Aaron for your response on my dilemma :)

I ended up following Aaron's advise and have been replacing php directories from a fresh version of Wordpress. I am still having to check pages and there are many more issues to surmount. I appreciate the feedback and hope to have the site back to normal after I'm done combing through the published material. I'm not using GoDaddy Shared Hosting, though I'm thinking I must have been hacked ... I just don't know how the site could be so riddled with errors if I wasn't.

Regardless, I blame GoDaddy for not getting me on the current PHP. So, I will need to bug them again tomorrow and see if they actually did what they said they did.. as Wordpress is still complaining that a PHP update is still Required.

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction! - Teale Miller